# Getting 404 on hosting two angular projects using nginx, one is parent and the another is subfolder

Tags: angular, nginx

```
location /project1/ {
     alias /var/www/html/project1/;
     try_files $uri /project1/index.html =404;
}

location / {                
            error_page 404  =200    /index.html;
}
```

I have two project, parent project sitting at /var/www/html and second project at /var/www/html/project1

I want the parent project to run normally and when the URL has project1 then the subfolder project1 to run. Its index file and assets. But I'm receiving 404 error for this.

Comment: If "project1" in the `location` and `alias` are identical text, use `root /var/www/html;` instead of the `alias` statement.

Comment: replacing alias keyword with root gives error 500 (internal server error)